How to assign function types to functions which accept generics
type TFormHookPerformValidation<formValuesT> = (params: {
  formValues: formValuesT,
  debugName?: string,
}) => {
  isPassing: boolean,
  fieldErrors: Record<string, unknown>,
  formError: string,
}

const performValidation: TFormHookPerformValidation = params => {

  // Do something based on params and return
  return {
    isPassing: true,
    fieldErrors: {},
    formError: ''
  }
}

TFormHookPerformValidation expects 1 generics, but when defining functions the type assignment will come first before the generics setup, so how can we accept generics in performValidation function and pass it to TFormHookPerformValidation.
Note: I can use Parameters and ReturnType but I would like to know if it's possible to assign the function type itself.

TFormHookPerformValidation not a generic function. That's a generic type that resolves to a non generic function. That means that formValuesT must be known when the type is used to know what the type of function needs to be.
If you want a generic function instead, you need to move the generic type parameter to the function itself.
type A<T> = (arg: T) => T
const a: A<number> = (arg) => arg // fine, a is typed (arg: number) => number
const aValueNumber = a(1) // number
const aValueString = a('str') // Type error

type B = <T>(arg: T) => T
const b: B = (arg) => arg // fine, b is typed <T>(arg: T) => T
const bValueNumber = b(1) // number
const bValueString = b('str') // string

Or in your case:
type TFormHookPerformValidation = <formValuesT>(params: {
  formValues: formValuesT,
  debugName?: string,
}) => {
  isPassing: boolean,
  fieldErrors: Record<string, unknown>,
  formError: string,
}

See playground

So do you want the generic type to be defined when you declare the function? Or when you call the function?

when calling the function, and looks the generic type should be on the right side, type TFormHookPerformValidation = <formValuesT> in that case.
